# Context swithcing impact on Capybara/Selenium click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

While running my test, it opens the browser window. If i switch the context to some other app running in my system when test is running, It doesn't click on the element, But if i stay in the test-running window, it clicks the element every time I run the test.
Does switching the context in system impacts the UI test run? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If you’re not running in a headless mode it will affect due to system focus